# Why are amsmath \xleftarrow & friends not working in listings?

Tags: listings, amsmath

I would like to use `literate=` to substitute `\xleftarrow` (and custom variants thereof) for some listing elements. See the example.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.rule}
A <*>  B
A <== B
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xLeftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\Leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[
    label=lst:rules,
    caption={Rules},
    literate={<*>}{$\xLeftrightarrow{*}{}$}3{<==}{$\xleftarrow{x}{}$}3
]{\jobname.rule}

$\xLeftrightarrow{*}{}$
$\xleftarrow{x}{}$

\end{document}
```

The text supposed to flow above the arrows, in the listing only, becomes appended. Can this be fixed? Alternatives compatible with listings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [listings manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), p. 50:

> Each 'printing unit' in *<replacement text> must* be in braces unless
>   it’s a single character.

So in this case you need `literate={<*>}{{$\xLeftrightarrow{*}{}$}}3{<==}{{$\xleftarrow{x}{}$}}3` with extra braces around the `$\xLeftrightarrow{*}{}$` and `\xLeftrightarrow{x}{}$`.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.rule}
A <*>  B
A <== B
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xLeftrightarrow}[2][]{\ext@arrow 0359\Leftrightarrowfill@{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\lstinputlisting[
    label=lst:rules,
    caption={Rules},
    literate={<*>}{{$\xLeftrightarrow{*}{}$}}3{<==}{{$\xleftarrow{x}{}$}}3
]{\jobname.rule}

$\xLeftrightarrow{*}{}$
$\xleftarrow{x}{}$

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]